# Lips Detection Not Working in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, face-detection, front-camera

I am unable to detect mouth using `vision.CascadeObjectDetector`. When I try it to extreme HD image it works fine. But on images/videos captured through Front Mobile Camera (5mp minimum), it gives error - **Please assist how can I get it working for all/most data.**

```
vidObj = VideoReader('faceVideo.mp4');
img = read(vidObj, 1);

faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth', 'MergeThreshold', 500);
cornerDetector = vision.CornerDetector('Method', 'Harris corner detection(Harris & Stephens)');

Irgb2gray = rgb2gray(img);

bboxes = step(faceDetector, Irgb2gray);

% Following line of code gives error
lips = imcrop(Irgb2gray, bboxes);
```

**Error is :**

> Error using corner>parseInputs (line 191) The value of 'Image' is
>   invalid. Expected input number 1, I, to be nonempty.
>
> Error in corner (line 80)
>       filter_coef,max_corners,quality_level] = parseInputs(varargin{:});
>
> Error in SmileyForVideo (line 22) C = corner(lips);

Comment: can you display Irgb2gray?

Comment: It actually displays irgb2gray and makes me manually select the lips region - which is impossible to do with hundreds of frame in a video

Comment: why does the error message contain the word corner multiple times if the error is caused by the imcrop line?

Comment: I commented the corner lines - The issue is persisting. It asked me to manually select Mouth region of a frame and worked fine for a single image. But when i give video as input, i cant manually do all mouth region marking - i cancel the window asking me to mark - and it produces the error mentioned in question.

Comment: Manual Marking mouth is impossible in case of video - cascadeObjectDetector fails to detect mouth and asks me to do it - how to avoid it.

Comment: to avoid the error, you should check that the cascade was able to find objects in the image, if not, skip the frame...

Comment: Amro@ i totally agree with your point of view - but it will waste most of data set which i have from front CAM. i want to solve this problem. Still Any smarter suggestion ?

Comment: please share the code/syntax as well to skip invalid cascade frame.